# States uniquely defined by operators

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, physics, operator-algebras, quantum-groups

In [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08384.pdf) article authors define quantum states $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ (elements of some Hilbert space H - in most simple case a $2\times 1$ complex vector such that $|\psi| = 1$) by a set of operators such that $s \left|\psi\right\rangle = \left|\psi\right\rangle$. See attached.

[image]

While the concept seems clear to me, and it *sounds* right, I can't produce such set to identify $$\left|\psi\right\rangle = \alpha [1,0]^T + \beta[0,1]^T$$ (so, not even in the simplest case.)

I am looking for some help in understanding how, given a state, one can generate such set of operators. Can it always be done? If yes, can one always define the smallest set of operators (in finite dimensional Hilbert space). Is there a sense of orthogonality, in similiar way elements of Hilbert space are linear combinations of orthogonal basis?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I think that the state $|\psi >$ is given, so it doesn't make sense to *define* the state, because it's already defined.

Comment: I am looking to find a set operators S such that this $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ is the only element of the space which is an eigenstate (eigenvector) of all $s \in S$ with eigenvalue 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically $S$ is a set of commuting operators and $\vert s\rangle$ is a common eigenvector of elements of this set.

To generate the two vectors you have, one might as well assume that elements of the set are diagonal, so pick them to be
$$
s_1=\hat 1\, , \qquad s_2=\sigma_z
$$
with $\sigma_z$ the Pauli matrix.  The common eigenvectors are $[1,0]^T$ and $[0,1]^T$.

To get $\psi=(\alpha,\beta)^T$ note first that $\vert\alpha\vert^2 +\vert \beta\vert^2=1$, construct the matrix
$$
U=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\alpha&-\beta^* \\ \beta&\alpha^*\end{array}\right)\, .
$$
and note that $U[1,0]^T=(\alpha,\beta)$ and $U$ is unitary.  Thus to get the set that will have $\psi$ as eigenvectors you need to conjugate $\hat 1$ and $\sigma_z$ by $U$, i.e. your new set is $\{\hat 1,U\sigma_zU^{-1}\}$.

If you need elements in $S$ to be unitary you can just use $e^{-i\alpha \sigma_z}$ instead of $\sigma_z$.  The key point is that the eigenvalues of your second operator should be distinct.

Comment: I see that $U \sigma_z U^{-1}$ indeed works, but why do we need the identity? Could you elaborate on why you choose $s_1$ and $s_2$ the way you do?

Comment: @PiotrBenedysiuk You don't strictly speaking need the unit, but often it's thrown in there so the dimension of the set is the same as that of the spece.  Leaving the unit aside, you need another operator with two different eigenvalues so you can distinguish the two basis states.  Choosing hermitian operators is convenient because the eigenvalues are real and $n$ commuting operators have $n$ orthogonal eigenvectors which span the space.